# How to pass different callbacks to same function in android

Tags: java, android, callback, android-volley, generic-callback

I am new to android and I am currently trying to make **volley post request** and get a response from an API. What I did is call a callback when the response is successful. This callback works fine if I call from a single class, for instance, say `MainActivity` callback method but not working if I try to call from other class. I tried to make the callback parameter in volleyAPIService as generic but can't succeed in it. Any kind of help would be appreciable.

**VolleyAPIService.java**

```
public class VolleyAPIService {

    public void volleyPost(final MainActivity.VolleyCallback callback, String URL, Map<String, String> param, Context context) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        final Map<String, String> params = param;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        callback.onSuccess(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {;
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

As I stated before I tried to make the first parameter of **volleyPost()** more generic to call this particular method from any class but couldn't succeed.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        companyLogin("abc", "123");
    }

    public interface VolleyCallback {
        void onSuccess(String result);
    }

    public void companyLogin(String companyname, String password) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "http://...";
        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", companyname);
        params.put("pwd", password);

        Intent volley_service = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VolleyAPIService.class);
        MainActivity.this.startService(volley_service);

        VolleyAPIService volleyAPIService = new VolleyAPIService();
        volleyAPIService.volleyPost(new VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                //do stuff here
                Log.d("VOLLEY", "onSuccess: " + result);
                if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                    Intent userLoginActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserLogin.class);
                    startActivity(userLoginActivity);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder login_failed = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    login_failed.setMessage("Login Failed, invalid credentials")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = login_failed.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        }, URL, params, MainActivity.this);
    }
}
```

I call `volleyPost()` with callback in `MainActivity.java`

**UserLogin.java**

```
public class UserLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);

        userLogin("xyz", "456", "1")
    }

    public interface VolleyCallback {
        void onSuccess(String result);
    }

    public void userLogin(String username, String password, String id) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "http://...";
        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("compId", id);

        Intent volley_service = new Intent(UserLogin.this, VolleyAPIService.class);
        UserLogin.this.startService(volley_service);

        VolleyAPIService volleyAPIService = new VolleyAPIService();
        volleyAPIService.volleyPost(new VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                //do stuff here
                Log.d("VOLLEY", "onSuccess: " + result);
                if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                    Intent userLoginActivity = new Intent(UserLogin.this, HomePage.class);
                    startActivity(userLoginActivity);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder login_failed = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserLogin.this);
                    login_failed.setMessage("Login Failed, invalid credentials")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = login_failed.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        }, URL, params, UserLogin.this);
    }
}
```

I try to call `volleyPost()` from this class too. I know that the **type of parameter callback mismatches** and tried to make the callback parameter generic for both the classes, I can't figure out a way to do that.

Any kind of help is appreciable and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend to have a separate interface class without keeping it inside of a `Class` or `Activity`.

So declare an interface like this. Create a separate file.

```
public interface VolleyCallback {
    void onSuccess(String result);
}
```

Then create a `public` instance of the `VolleyCallback` interface in your `VolleyAPIService` class like the following. Remove the parameter from the `volleyPost` method for cleaner implementation.

```
public class VolleyAPIService {

    public VolleyCallback callback; 

    public void volleyPost(String URL, Map<String, String> param, Context context) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        final Map<String, String> params = param;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        callback.onSuccess(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {;
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Now from your `MainActivity`, implement the interface that you have created and override the callback function like the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VolleyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        companyLogin("abc", "123");
    }
    public interface VolleyCallback {
        void onSuccess(String result);
    }

    public void companyLogin(String companyname, String password) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "http://...";
        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", companyname);
        params.put("pwd", password);

        Intent volley_service = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VolleyAPIService.class);
        MainActivity.this.startService(volley_service);

        VolleyAPIService volleyAPIService = new VolleyAPIService();

        // Assign the callback here to listen the response from the API service.
        volleyAPIService.callback = this; 
        volleyAPIService.volleyPost(URL, params, MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        // Handle the success or failure here
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            Intent userLoginActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserLogin.class);
            startActivity(userLoginActivity);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder login_failed = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            login_failed.setMessage("Login Failed, invalid credentials")
                 .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                     }
                 });

             AlertDialog alert = login_failed.create();
             alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Do the same for your `UserLogin` class.

In case of having multiple API calls in a single `Activity` or `Fragment`, you might want to keep a flag in the `VolleyAPIService` class and passing that to the callback function you can detect which API response you are getting in your `onSuccess` callback.

Hope that is clear. Please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Reaz. The above explanation was clear and worked perfectly. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Great to know that I could help. You are most welcome. :)